# Enable SHIFT key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an input where user's firstname will be put on. I disabled all keys EXCEPT a-z and 0-9 and it works fine. 
I want to allow SHIFT key too so when the user wants to capitalize a letter he can do it. I already tried some solutions but doesnt work.

```
$('#firstname').on('keypress', function(e){
  return e.metaKey ||
    e.which <= 0 ||
    e.which == 8 ||
    /[a-z 0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
})
```

Comment: You should ignore the case on the RegEx. Use `/i` on the end of it.

Comment: Why this was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the character range to you regular expression.

```js
$('#firstname').on('keypress', function(e){
  return e.metaKey ||
    e.which <= 0 ||
    e.which == 8 ||
    /[a-zA-Z0-9 ]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
})
```

Comment: You can also use `/i` on the end too.

Comment: Is the snippet supposed to run? It only displays ReferenceError.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No -- it required some context which wasn't present. I've disabled the snippet.